# how to change fab menu buttons images in android

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-drawable, floating-action-button

[image: screenshot of fab buttons in xml]i am using 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4' library to show fab buttons, they are working correctly but when i tried to change the images for the buttons then the images appear to be very small and the fab menu button's image didn't changed at all.
Can anybody tell me how to resolve this issue?

here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tabla_cuerpo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="362dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#BCBCBC">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#BCBCBC"                android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Case#"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#BCBCBC"                android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Client"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1c"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#BCBCBC"                android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Case Amount"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1d"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#BCBCBC"                android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Received"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1e"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#BCBCBC"                android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Reminder"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1f"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#BCBCBC"                android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Remarks"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                  <TextView

                android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Case#"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Client"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2c"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Case Amount"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2d"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Received"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2e"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Reminder"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2f"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Remarks"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Case#"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Client"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3c"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Case Amount"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3d"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Received"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3e"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Reminder"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3f"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellshape"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Remarks"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#ccffffff"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#DA4336"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="#E75043"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:fab_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:fab_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/add_payment_btn"
            fab:fab_label="ADD PAYMENT"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/editcasesicon"
            fab:fab_label="EDIT PAYMENT"
            fab:fab_size="mini" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
</FrameLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/delete"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml code if possible.

Comment: @sathishgadde please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Am just used the same library .Set your drawable image size as 24dp height and 24dp width.am post my sample code screen shot.i hope it can usefull for you.

You dont use both   and 
at a time use only any one FloatingActionButton .Otherwise raise error during declaration of control [FloatingActionButton].
[image]
[image]

If you want to chnage FloatingActionMenu image then you can change image drawable from your library Project,open FloatingActionMenu.class and from that file line no. 161 change your image drawable whatever you want..

Comment: sorry, you are said that " images appear to be very small and the fab menu button's image didn't changed at all  ". Your code is right.But you just change  fab menu drawable[Image]  size changed as Height:24dp and weight:24dp

Comment: And tell me which image you want to change.

Comment: actually i want to remove the padding inside the buttons, those extra spaces from inside which makes the button look smaller

Comment: Ok. Actually we are using third party library that size can set programatically set in FloatingActionButton class .in my screen shot that images looking perfect for you or not.Padding and everything is perfect then let me know.

Comment: i don't want any space inside the round shape of fab buttons, and your screenshot's fab buttons have spaces

Comment: And where is that folder which you show in your first screenshot of clan library?